# How to manipulate resultset returned by a stored procedure called inside the stored procedure in DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, resultset

I need to create a stored procedure (SP_CALLER) that will call another stored procedure (SP_CALLED) and select its returned resultset.

How can we query the returned result set??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMANAME.SP_CALLER(@PARAM1 INT, @PARAM2 VARCHAR)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

P1:BEGIN

DECLARE VALUE1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE VALUE2 VARCHAR DEFAULT 'TEST';

CALL SCHEMANAME.SP_CALLED @XPARAM1=VALUE1, @XPARAM2=VALUE2; --<-- returns a result set

SELECT * 
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM (resultsetquery); --<-- from the returned result set of sp_called



SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTABLE a, 
SCHEMANAME.TABLE2 b
WHERE a.COL1 = @PARAM1 AND b.COL2 = @PARAM2;



END P1
```

UPDATE 04/04/2019:

The docs were really helpful, but i was stuck here.. how can i query the resultset that allocated to this variable ('cur') and return it as the new result set of my stored procedure (SCHEMANAME.SP_CALLER)???

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMANAME.SP_CALLER() DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

P1:BEGIN

DECLARE loc_cursor RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;


CALL SCHEMANAME.SPNAME();

ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (loc_cursor) WITH PROCEDURE SCHEMANAME.SPNAME; 
ALLOCATE cur CURSOR FOR RESULT SET loc_cursor;


CLOSE cur;

END P1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0009168.html).

The key details to learn about are locators,  `associate result set locators`  and then `allocate ... cursor for result set`.  After that is done, your calling procedure can treat the cursor just like any other (fetching rows , close etc).

So if your nested procedures returns 1 result set, your calling sproc will declare a [locator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_refs2resultsetlocatorvars.html),  [associate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005645.html) the result-set locator with your called-procedure, then [allocate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005642.html) a cursor to consume the result-set.   Study the documentation for each of the involved statements.

Apart from the above, if you will always filter the result-set, why not make a procedure that performs the filtering at source (to avoid slow double filtering)? You can also have a procedure create a session-table and have callers access that session-table. Or use a table-function to return exactly what is needed?